# Gatsby - how to fix "eliminate render-blocking resources" (google fonts)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, pagespeed, google-fonts

I am working on my first app in React (Gatsby) and Pagespeed Insights shows me the following error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtRev.png)

I added Google Fonts using a plugin **gatsby-plugin-google-fonts**

```
resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          `roboto mono\:400,700` // you can also specify font weights and styles
        ],
        display: 'swap'
      }
```

Is there any way to fix it?

You can see this app here:
https://cssgenerator.pl/

Github: https://github.com/marekfoltanski/cssgenerator

Answer (score 0):

From https://cssgenerator.pl I can see it has generated this

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700&amp;display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Which does not provide `font-display: swap;`

The link should have been

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Which will provide `font-display: swap;`

> Is there any way to fix it?

Ensure the correct link is applied in the header.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I am not familiar with `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts` API.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using the `v2` API along with [`gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2/). In your case, it seems that the generated link is not loading properly the fonts. Something like this should work:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-v2`,
  options: {
    fonts: [
      {
        family: `Roboto Mono:wght@400;700`,
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

It defaults to `display= swap`.

In both cases (yours and mine, `v1` and `v2`), check the generated link in the head of your HTML output, copy the link and paste it in your browser to see what's fetching and how.